# Subscript vs. Superscript conflict

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, subscript, superscript

***<sub>Background:</sub>***

I'm trying to write a module to concatenate strings with it's formatting. Therefor I'm looking in all `Font` properties that could matter, including `Subscript` and `Superscript`.

---

***<sub>Sample Data:</sub>***

Imagine in `A1`:

[image: SO SO]

---

***<sub>Sample Code:</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

With Sheet1.Range("B1")
    .Value = .Offset(0, -1).Value
    For x = 1 To .Characters.Count
        .Characters(x, 1).Font.Subscript = .Offset(0, -1).Characters(x, 1).Font.Subscript
        .Characters(x, 1).Font.Superscript = .Offset(0, -1).Characters(x, 1).Font.Superscript
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Result:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>Question:</sub>***

If I would go through this code step-by-step using <kbd>F8</kbd> I can see the characters that are supposed to be subscript become subscript, but will loose it's properties value when the superscript value is passed. The other way around works fine, meaning the superscript properties stay intact.

This procedure is part of a larger procedure where for example I tried to convert this:

[image]

```html
Sub ConcatStringsWithFormat()

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim props(9) As Variant, arr As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Long, y As Long: y = 0

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A3")
With Application
    .Trim (rng)
    arr = rng: arr = .Transpose(.Index(arr, 0, 1))
End With
    
For Each cell In rng
    If Len(cell) > 0 Then
        y = y + 1
        For x = 1 To cell.Characters.Count
            props(0) = cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.Bold
            props(1) = cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.ColorIndex
            props(2) = cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.FontStyle
            props(3) = cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.Italic
            props(4) = cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.Size
            props(5) = cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.Strikethrough
            props(6) = cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.Subscript
            props(7) = cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.Superscript
            props(8) = cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.TintAndShade
            props(9) = cell.Characters(x, 1).Font.Underline
            dict.Add y, props
            y = y + 1
        Next x
    End If
Next cell

With Sheet1.Cells(1, 2)
    .Value = Application.Trim(Join(arr, " "))
    For x = 1 To .Characters.Count
        If Mid(.Value, x, 1) <> " " Then
            .Characters(x, 1).Font.Bold = dict(x)(0)
            .Characters(x, 1).Font.ColorIndex = dict(x)(1)
            .Characters(x, 1).Font.FontStyle = dict(x)(2)
            .Characters(x, 1).Font.Italic = dict(x)(3)
            .Characters(x, 1).Font.Size = dict(x)(4)
            .Characters(x, 1).Font.Strikethrough = dict(x)(5)
            .Characters(x, 1).Font.Subscript = dict(x)(6)
            .Characters(x, 1).Font.Superscript = dict(x)(7)
            .Characters(x, 1).Font.TintAndShade = dict(x)(8)
            .Characters(x, 1).Font.Underline = dict(x)(9)
        End If
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

Resulting in:

[image]

As you can see, it's just the subscript properties that get lost. Any thought on why this happens and also on how to overcome this? It's apparent that a cell will allow both properties to be true on different characters if you manually tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that swapping the lines will give the correct result:

---

***<sub>Wrong</sub>***

[image]

```
With Sheet1.Range("B1")
    .Value = .Offset(0, -1).Value
    For x = 1 To .Characters.Count
        .Characters(x, 1).Font.Subscript = .Offset(0, -1).Characters(x, 1).Font.Subscript
        .Characters(x, 1).Font.Superscript = .Offset(0, -1).Characters(x, 1).Font.Superscript
    Next x
End With
```

---

***<sub>Right</sub>***

[image]

```
With Sheet1.Range("B1")
    .Value = .Offset(0, -1).Value
    For x = 1 To .Characters.Count
        .Characters(x, 1).Font.Superscript = .Offset(0, -1).Characters(x, 1).Font.Superscript
        .Characters(x, 1).Font.Subscript = .Offset(0, -1).Characters(x, 1).Font.Subscript
    Next x
End With
```

---

Swapping the lines around worked. With no other explaination than that these properties are also below eachother under cell settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just test before setting those properties:

```
Sub Test()

With Sheet1.Range("B2")
    .Value = .Offset(0, -1).Value
    For x = 1 To .Characters.Count
      If .Offset(0, -1).Characters(x, 1).Font.Subscript Then
         .Characters(x, 1).Font.Subscript = True
      ElseIf .Offset(0, -1).Characters(x, 1).Font.Superscript Then
         .Characters(x, 1).Font.Superscript = True
      End If
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh, duhh. Thanks Rory, implemented in my module as `If dict(x)(6) = True Then` and `ElseIf dict(x)(7) = True Then`. Any thoughts on why the property gets reset to nothing? Initially I thought to avoid an `IF` because I can just read both properties from a character just fine. Implementing however was a different story.

Comment: I guess in the programmer's mind, setting either property to `False` was the same as saying "this should be **normal** text"

Comment: I have just found out that swapping the two lines around also solved the issue :S....

Comment: @JvdV Yes it looks like superscript has some sort of priority. If there's any sort of superscript in there (even if it's one letter at the end and all the rest of the cell is subscript), it's always the superscript option that is part selected in the format cells dialog.