# Macro to concatenate the two adjacent cells by keeping the format of the first cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using the below code to merge two adjacent cells with line break but I would like to keep the source formatting of the first cell which has an underline. How can I embed the code line in the below code to keep the underline formatting of the first cell. Please look at the below image, I need something like this.

[image]

But the current macro is only merging but not keeping the underline format.

[image]

I also need to merge the results in single cells with the source formating.

```
    Sub linebreak()

Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Range("K2:K51")  'Set the range of the first column cells

For Each c In myRange.Cells
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        'Concatenate in 3rd column
        If c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = c.Value
        Else
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = c.Value & Chr(10) & c.Offset(0, 1).Value
            'Apply formatting with preserving colors
            c.Offset(0, 2).Characters(Len(CStr(c.Value)) + 2, Len(CStr(c.Offset(0, 1).Value))).Font.Color = c.Offset(0, 1).Font.Color
            c.Offset(0, 2).Characters(Len(CStr(c.Value)) + 2, Len(CStr(c.Offset(0, 1).Value))).Font.Italic = c.Offset(0, 1).Font.Italic
            c.Offset(0, 2).Characters(Len(CStr(c.Value)) + 2, Len(CStr(c.Offset(0, 1).Value))).Font.Bold = c.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold
        End If
    End If
Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: You can't concatenate text and maintain their formatting. You need to go through it's characters. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59088629/9758194) is an example.

Comment: @JvdV: He cannot to that in a text resulting from a formula. But he can do it for an ordinary concatenation...

Comment: That would be so error prone @FaneDuru ("error" as in unwanted results)

Comment: @JvdV: Not at all, If you know what you are doing, I think. Look at my answer, please.

Comment: @FaneDuru. What if `c.Offset(0,1)` has Underline/Bold/Italic or any other formatting (or even per character). I would always opt to iterate characters to be save. Unless in the case of OP, the left column is the ***only*** value that can be formatted as a ***whole***. Even when you know what you are doing, this is a dangerous assumption.

Comment: @JvdV: I was referring at what he asked. But I can format character by character if necessary. Of course, all the font parameters necessary to be passed to be defined prior to the code building... Everything (necessary) can be previously  memorized in an array and dropped when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, please:

```
Sub linebreak()
Dim myRange As Range, c As Range
Set myRange = Range("K2:K6")  'Set the range of the first column cells

For Each c In myRange.Cells
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        'Concatenate in 3rd column
        If c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = c.Value
        Else
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = c.Value & Chr(10) & c.Offset(0, 1).Value
            'Apply formatting with preserving colors
            c.Offset(0, 2).Characters(1, Len(CStr(c.Value))).Font.Color = c.Font.Color
            c.Offset(0, 2).Characters(1, Len(CStr(c.Value))).Font.Italic = c.Font.Italic
            c.Offset(0, 2).Characters(1, Len(CStr(c.Value))).Font.Bold = c.Font.Bold
            c.Offset(0, 2).Characters(1, Len(CStr(c.Value))).Font.Underline = c.Font.Underline
        End If
    End If
 Next c
End Sub
```

You have to start characters to be formatted from 1, use `Len(c.Value)` for formatting length, to apply the format of `c` and use `Underline` for doing what you wanted...

Here, solution for your last request:

```
Sub AllConc()
 Dim myRange As Range, c As Range, strC As String
 Set myRange = Range("K2:K5")
 For Each c In myRange
    If c.Value <> Empty Then
        strC = strC & c.Value & vbCrLf
    End If
 Next
 strC = left(strC, Len(strC) - 1)
 Range("K6").Value = strC
End Sub
```

The concatenated string is returned at "K6".

Comment: @Revan Erraboina: I am not sure I understand what you need... I suppose you understand that format is lost not because it is the VBA code result. But now, I do not understand the second part of your comment. Would you like that all the content of the range "K2:K5" to be concatenated in one cell? Each value on one line? Independent of empty cells in the range? If yes, where this cell keeping the concatenation must be? I have availability only for some minutes...

Comment: Now the macro is combing cells K2&L2, K3&L3, K4&L4 and showing the result in M2,M3,M4 respectively  without effecting th soure format. I am only asking is there a way we can merge the results in M column (i.e. M2,M3,M4) in cell N2 without effecting the format. I have used our second code but with required ranges, I am able to merge but the underline is not working. Please check.

Comment: @Revan Erraboina: When "now"? The last solution, as I understood it, or the first one? **"all the content of the range "K2:K5" to be concatenated in one cell"** (you said that) is what the second piece of code does. I do not understand what you want! Sorry... Didn't you say that you "are loosing the format" when paste somewhere else? Underline is part of the format... If you are able to clearly explain, in a short phrase, what you need, if I will understand I will help you. But, without making reference to the passed. **Only what you need!**

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong column with `Offset`. Your main reference is:

```
Set myRange = Range("K2:K51")  'Set the range of the first column cells
```

According to your own code, this is the first column of cells.

And later on you do `c.Offset(0, 1).Font.Color`, so you are referencing column L, where there is no format applied. IT should be `c.Font.Color`

Try:

```
Sub linebreak()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim c As Range

Set myRange = Range("K2:K51")  'Set the range of the first column cells

For Each c In myRange.Cells
    If c.Value <> "" Then
    'Concatenate in 3rd column
        If c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = c.Value
        Else
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = c.Value & Chr(10) & c.Offset(0, 1).Value
            'Apply formatting with preserving colors
            c.Offset(0, 2).Characters(Len(CStr(c.Value)) + 2, Len(CStr(c.Offset(0, 1).Value))).Font.Color = c.Font.Color
            c.Offset(0, 2).Characters(Len(CStr(c.Value)) + 2, Len(CStr(c.Offset(0, 1).Value))).Font.Italic = c.Font.Italic
            c.Offset(0, 2).Characters(Len(CStr(c.Value)) + 2, Len(CStr(c.Offset(0, 1).Value))).Font.Bold = c.Font.Bold
        End If
    End If
Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: I did not quite get it, could you please explain little more and in which part of the code do I need to change t get the result.